# ComboBox DataSource And Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I add Data Model Entity to my project named `publishingCompanyEntities` And added ComboBox in my winform.
but when i want to bind my list of authors into my combo box as data source has been filled with data , but `cmoAuthors.Items.Count` returns 0 but `cmoAuthors.DataSource.Count` returns 2 item

```
        publishContext = new publishingCompanyEntities();
        cmoAuthors.DataSource = publishContext.Authors;
        cmoAuthors.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
```

Comment: Try calling `cmoAuthors.Invalidate()` and then check if the `Items.Count` are updated.

Comment: no, it returns 0 yet , comboBox in winform is empty too!

Comment: what if you change the source to this: `publishContext.Authors.ToList()`

Comment: yes , `ToList()` Solved Problem . but why compiler doesnt said that i cant populate dbSet as Data Source ! :|

Comment: I have combined the infomation in my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add `.ToList()` to the Authors EntitySet.

```
publishContext = new publishingCompanyEntities();
        cmoAuthors.DataSource = publishContext.Authors.ToList();
        cmoAuthors.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
        cmoAuthors.Invalidate();
```

The reason is that an EntitySet is *not* a actual collection. It's a query (`IQueryable`), and  it seems that the ComboBox is not smart enought to detect that.

Calling the `ToList()` materialize the `publishContext.Authors` into objects.

For some reason, the ComboBox does not update it `Items` Collection, then a new DataSource is detected. `Invalidate()` forces the Control to redraw iself, and in the process, updating its Items collection.

Comment: is it okay  if i dont use Invalidate()?

Comment: @r.hamd well, **im** not gonna force you :) Only you know what is best in your senario.

Answer (score 3):

you need to provide the valuemember property. [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx)

```
cmoAuthors.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
cmoAuthors.ValueMember = "yourValueProperty";
```